# How can I test for a given sum in all combinations of multiple sets?

Tags: clojure

I'm working on [Problem 131](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/131) from 4Clojure site.

What kind of "for" statement might I add to combinatorially check each of these sets for a subset of items which sums to 0?

In particular I had a few questions here:

1. Is there any clojure function which takes an arbitrary number of sets?
2. If so, how can I generate all subsets AND sum those subsets without adding an extra Clojure to this code, or am I mistaken?

I need to fill in the __ part.

```
(= true  (__ #{-1 1 99}
             #{-2 2 888}
             #{-3 3 7777}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You mean sets (instead of maps)? But actually, that doesn't matter.
   For example, [count](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/count) takes one argument, but you can make anonymous function, that takes arbitrary number of arguments.
   `((fn [& args] (map count args)) #{-1 1 99} #{-2 2 888} #{-3 3 7777})`
   or
   `(#(map count %&) #{-1 1 99} #{-2 2 888} #{-3 3 7777})`
2. You can use [subsets](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/combinatorics-api.html#clojure.contrib.combinatorics/subsets) from `combinatorics` contrib to generate all subsets and then `reduce` them with `+`
   `#(map (partial reduce +) (subsets %))`

So, this problem can be solved with these two functions:

```
(defn sums [s] 
  (set (map #(reduce + %) (rest (subsets s)))))

(defn cmp [& sets]
  (not (empty? (apply intersection (map sums sets)))))
```

I wasn't able to make `4clojure` import libraries from contrib, so I leave it as is.

Comment: definetly helpful, but this won't answer the 4clojure question .....  Any other tries ?

Comment: The above, combined with a mechanism for creating all subsets of a set, should be sufficient for you to figure it out.

Comment: @jayunit100: You may want to solve [problem 85](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/85) first. Power set (minus empty set) is exactly that another mechanism.